# PostgreSQL Loop jsonb rows in 2 recordsets and find change

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I am a novice in PostgreSQL world, and not aware about its offerings much. I have a requirement where I have to find changes in values in 2 recordsets while parsing the JSONB Column in PostgreSQL. Here is what I am talking.

I want to create a PostgreSQL FUNCTION that will accept 4 parameters
{dynamicstring1 character varying, dynamicstring2 character varying, columnsToCheck character varying, uniqueColumns character varying}

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ChangeTrack(dynamicstring1 character varying,
                                            dynamicstring2 character varying,
                                            UniqueCols character varying,
                                            columnsToCheck character varying)
RETURNS VOID AS $$

$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Inside the function I will execute these 2 dynamic strings via the EXECUTE function that should give me the result sets like below:

Data Set from dynamicstring1

```
1,  25193,{"ID":1,"Age":12.1,"Name":"P1","Address":"Add11"}
2,  25193,{"ID":2,"Age":13.1,"Name":"P2","Address":"Add21"}
3,  25193,{"ID":3,"Age":14.1,"Name":"P3","Address":"Add31"}
4,  25193,{"ID":4,"Age":15.1,"Name":"P4","Address":"Add41"}
5,  25193,{"ID":5,"Age":16.1,"Name":"P5","Address":"Add51"}
6,  25193,{"ID":6,"Age":17.1,"Name":"P6","Address":"Add61"}
```

Data Set from dynamicstring2

```
7,  25194,{"ID":1,"Age":12,"Name":"P1","Address":"Add1"} 
8,  25194,{"ID":2,"Age":13,"Name":"P2","Address":"Add2"}
9,  25194,{"ID":3,"Age":14,"Name":"P3","Address":"Add3"}
10, 25194,{"ID":4,"Age":15,"Name":"P4","Address":"Add4"}
11, 25194,{"ID":5,"Age":16,"Name":"P5","Address":"Add5"}
12, 25194,{"ID":6,"Age":17,"Name":"P6","Address":"Add6"}
```

The table that has this data is

```
Result(UId PK bigint, ResultId bigint, Results jsonB).
```

The expectation is simple, that I should loop thru the records in **Data Set from dynamicstring1**, taking one row at a time, find the same row in **Data Set from dynamicstring2** and do a string comparison between the columns mentioned in the 
**columnsToCheck** array between both rows.

**columnsToCheck** is an string array that contains columns to be watched out for. It will have the value as ["Age","Address"]. So, both of these need to be tracked for change.

The way of finding the row in **Data Set from dynamicstring2** should be : When the row from **Data Set from dynamicstring1** is being looped, we take the values from the columns mentioned in **uniqueCols** and look for the same values to find a corresponding row in **Data Set from dynamicstring2**.. Hence  **uniqueCols** would be another string array with value as ["Id","Name"].This will ensure that we are always comparing the records with same Id and Name in **Data Set from dynamicstring1** to that of **Data Set from dynamicstring2**

I may be sounding complex here, but I am more of a SQL guy who has not dealt with JSON parsing before. Seeking some good help here that can take me forward.

Comment: Please you [edit] your question and add some sample _input_ data.

Comment: The data in the Result table is going to be in the same form as provided with Data Set from dynamicstring1 and Data Set from dynamicstring2.

Comment: I am not asking for the "format" of the input data, but for an actual **example** of the input data that you expect would generate the result you have shown

Comment: The actual data cannot be provided due to copyright reasons. Sorry. But the data that I have provided carries the same behavior that resides in the actual data.